# Libgdx how to store data for collision detection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, libgdx, collision-detection

I am developing a game using libgdx scene2d. All my objects are subclasses of `Actor` (we call them `GameObject`), so they allready have position and size, but all in separate fields (`float x; float y; float height; float width;)`. For collision detection i use some self made methods, but also some methods of `Intersector`. The `Intersector` methods need `Vector2` parameters for position and size. So i have to create `Vector2` objects out of the `Actor`s fields, **every render cycle**. And this is bad for garbage collection. My only idea to avoid this is to have a `Vector2 position` and `Vector2 size` in my `GameObject`s. But then i have redundant data and I would need to override the getter and setter methods to update the `Vector2` and the `Actor`s data (needed for drawing). Is there another, better way? Is redundant data better then the problem with the garbage?  Or should i copy the `Intersector`s methods and edit them to use `float x` and `float y` instead of `Vector2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redundant data are pretty bad as redundancy leads to time and memory overhead and also to programming errors. Modifying a third party method is bad as i means redoing it when it gets upgraded. Somehow all solutions are bad, but you should *always measure it*. Is the garbage a real problem?

I'd switch to using `Vector2` everywhere, if possible. You could also recycle existing Vector and fill it with your data. This eliminates the garbage problem, but there's still the cost for copying.

The final solution is up to you. I doubt that anybody could say for sure what's best for you.

Comment: Actually the garbage is no problem, cause i just started the game and the only objects which have to detect collisions are the walls, my player and the bullets (maybe about 20). But later when i add enemies, which also can shoot i think it could be a problem. The modifying a third party thing was more like creating my own "MyIntersector" class, with the methods i need, using the algorithm of libgdx Intersector. The redundant data would be in every object, so yea with enemies, which shoot bullets it could be a lot. What do you suggest in this case?

Comment: I wouldn't do any ugly solution before seeing any real problem. A lot of garbage is bad, but garbage living only for a short time is pretty harmful (the GC cost grows with surviving objects). The intersection problem is simple enough for a home-made solution, so it's fine. The only solution I'd exclude now is the redundancy - it's just too ugly.

Comment: Okay so i don't modify my collision detection for now and if i run into problems with the gc i will write my own collision detection. I have seen, that the only method, which really needs Vector2 is circle-linesegment intersection, which i only use for player vs wall and enemie vs wall. So i think the garbage won't be a lot. At least i hope :P Thanks a lot +1!

Comment: @Springrbua: Nice. And don't forget about the [the root to all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Haha yea i noticed this many times xD I worried about how to implement a pool for my bullets to avoid garbage collection even before i had bullets in my game :P

Comment: @Springrbua: Even before you knew there'll be any bullets. :D Or a game. :D Similar thoughts happen to me too, but be assured that pooling is nearly always counter-productive (really huge objects, hard to compute things, and DB-connections apart).

Comment: Yea i think i won't add pooling. Libgdx supports pooling, but the easy way to pool is only possible with no parameter constructors and i need some parameters. So i would need to invest hours only for a pool implementation... I don't think that it will be a huge performance loss so no pool for me :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46156/discussion-between-springrbua-and-maaartinus)

Answer (score 5):

LibGdx has a nice `Pools` class, so why don't you use it?

Here is an example:

```
Vector2 position = Pools.obtain(Vector2.class);
// use your Vector2 for something
Pools.free(position);
```

You will not have any redundant data, it will still be fast and much more predictable than having objects unnecessarily allocated on each frame.

My 2 cents:

I agree that premature optimization is a bad idea, but in my experience it is beneficial to take certain design approaches when making certain types of applications.

Specifically, I believe it is a good idea to avoid unnecessary object allocations on each frame when making games, especially for platforms such as Android.

These allocation might not be a problem now, or for some specific devices, but it might come back and bite you in the ass, and you might be forced to do some non-trivial changes to your code - this has happened to me.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I think i will stay with my current code. But if i run into problems i ll try this one. It won't be a big code change as i only have to replace the "new Vector2()" with "Pools.obtain(Vector2.class)". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Given that `Vector2` needs 16 bytes only and that `Pools.obtain(Vector2.class)` needs to locate the right list for the class (hashing) and get the object, it looks pretty expensive to me. But I have hardly any experience with Android, so it can't say much; anyway, even if it costs more time than the allocation and collection, it still may make sense as it may avoid GC pauses.